# ¿Cómo llamar a una función javascript desde fuera del bloque en que se encuentra definida?

Tags: javascript

Partiendo del siguiente código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        function one()
        {
            console.log('clicked "One"');
        }

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
            console.log('Document it´s ready !');

            function two()
            {
                console.log('clicked "One"');
            };
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            console.log('Document it´s ready !');

            function three()
            {
                console.log('clicked "Two"');
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="One" onclick="one()">
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="Two" onclick="two()">
    <input type="button" class="btn" value="Three" onclick="three()">
</body>
</html>
```

Ocurre lo siguiente:

Al hacer click sobre el primer botón aparece el mensaje `clicked "One"` en la consola.

Al hacer click sobre el segundo o tercer botón aparece un *mensaje de error indicando que la función no se encuentra definida*, por ejemplo:

```
JS - Ambito funciones.html:39 Uncaught ReferenceError: two is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick
```

¿Se puede llamar a las funciones `two()` y `three()` desde fuera de los bloques en que fueron definidas?

Comment: podrías probar `(new ($(document).ready)).three();` para ver si podes escopear la función, el scope de un listener ni idea si puede ser recuperado, btw interesante pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que la función la llames desde dentro del listener pero que sea definida desde fuera, ya que no existe fuera de ese ámbito, de manera que podrás llamarla desde cualquier parte.
Las funciones declaradas de esta forma son solo cuando no vas a volver a utilizarlas.